# how can I compare the value of an element with the next element

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

how can I compare an element in a list with the next element to see whether they're the same?  Let's say I have a list and I want to use for loop to iterate through the list and print out how many times the number is there before different number comes.

```
str_n = "5223888"
count = 1

#print(len(str_n))

number = [int(x) for x in str_n]
#print(number)

for i in number:
    while number[i] == number[i+1]:
        count+=1
        i+=1
    print(count, " ", i)
```

expected output:

```
15221338
```

Comment: Are you wondering how to compare adjacent elements in a list? Can you explain your expected output in more detail?

Comment: I have a list = [5,2,2,3,8,8,8]
I want to iterate through this list, and check whether the next element of the list is the same value of current. If it is the same, then the counter is increased until the next element doesnt have the same value of the current. 
Then I want to print out, as how we read it. For instance, one 5 two 2s one 3 three 8s (15221338)

Comment: this is how i wrote in c++, but it cant hande big data

int arr[6];
    int counter = 1;

    int number = 111522;
    for (int i = 5; i >= 0; i--) {
        arr[i] = number % 10;
        number /= 10;
    }

    for (int i(0); i < 6; i++)
    {
        while (arr[i] == arr[(i+1)])
        {
            counter++;
            i++;
        }
       cout << counter << arr[i];
       counter=1;
    }

Comment: So overall your program is trying to get the occurrence of each element in the list? If so your implementation attempt at looking at the next element won't work since you are not considering occurrences before the element at that index in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me some time to understand what you where asking for . In your situation its best to go with a while loop

```
str_n = "5223888" 
#print(len(str_n))

number = [int(x) for x in str_n]
#print(number)
i=0;
while(i<len(number)): 
    storei=i
    count = 1
    while i+1<len(number) and number[i] == number[i+1]  :
        count+=1
        i+=1
    i+=1
    print("number is "+str(number[storei])+" count is "+str(count)))
```

OUTPUT

```
number is 5 count is 1
number is 2 count is 2
number is 3 count is 1
number is 8 count is 3
```

**EDIT**
in python3 to print the output you require you need to specify

```
str_n = "522388"
#print(len(str_n))

number = [int(x) for x in str_n]
#print(number)
i=0;
while(i<len(number)): 
    storei=i
    count = 1
    while i+1<len(number) and number[i] == number[i+1]  :
        count+=1
        i+=1
    i+=1
    #print("number is "+str(number[storei])+" count is "+str(count))
    print(str(count)+str(number[storei]),end="")
```

And in python 2 to get the exact output you need to specify like

```
str_n = "522388"

import sys
#print(len(str_n))

number = [int(x) for x in str_n]
#print(number)
i=0;
while(i<len(number)): 
    storei=i
    count = 1
    while i+1<len(number) and number[i] == number[i+1]  :
        count+=1
        i+=1
    i+=1
    #print("number is "+str(number[storei])+" count is "+str(count))
    sys.stdout.write(str(count)+str(number[storei]))
```

Comment: is there any way to print it in one line?

Comment: @Amrin are you using python 2 or 3?

Comment: im using python 3

Answer (score 1):

**Mistakes**

1. When you do `for i in number`, you iterate over "2" two times and "8" three times which gives wrong output.
2. You did not initialize `count` to zero at each iteration.
3. `for i in number` iterates over the values in `number`, not the index

**Correct code**

You can use the following code:

```
str_n = "5223888"

number = [int(x) for x in str_n]

for i in set(number):
    print("Element " + str(i) + " occurs " + str(number.count(i)) + " times")
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the code, found what I want. But if I were to print only str(number.count(i)) and  str(i), why is the number printed on different line instead of one line?

Comment: @Amrin That is how the print works in python. I know it is different from C++ cout

Answer (score 0):

When you wrote `for i in number` you probably meant `for i in range(len(number))` which would make `i` be the *indices* of the `number` list.

That being said, you don't really need the indices; when you say `for num in number`, `num` is the actual number in the list. You can accomplish what you want without indices with something like this:

```
count = 0
current = number[0]

for num in number:
  if num == current:
    count += 1
  else:
    print(count, current)    
    current = num
    count = 1

print(count, current) # print the last count
```

This gives us:

```
1 5
2 2
1 3
3 8
```